# Need to read values App.config from class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a project(web app) and referenced a class library to it, created config file and added values to it, now I need to read values from app.config from the class library.

is there a way to do it?

I researched but could not find anything.

Comment: _"I researched but could not find anything"_ - show _what_ you researched, as this question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically only want one config file. If this is a web application, it will be the web.config file. You can read this from a class library by adding a reference to `System.Configuration` and using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Settings["settingkey"]` to access it.

If you really need to access a separate app.config file, you will need to know the path to it and use something like:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = pathToAppConfigFile;
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager
    .OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
setting = config.AppSetting.Settings["settingkey"];
```

Comment: thanks steve, this resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
```

is the way to go. See this link for further reference and functioning example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx